# Pushing an image into private registry doesn't work if I deleted this image before via Registry API v2 call

Tags: docker, garbage-collection, docker-registry

I have difficulties with pushing images into private registry.
Let me explain my use case:
I have Regisrty container which configured with detele:eanbled:true

```
docker exec -it registry2 bin/registry --version
```

bin/registry github.com/docker/distribution v2.6.1

1) pull the new image

```
~ # docker pull php:7.0.10-alpine
7.0.10-alpine: Pulling from library/php
e110a4a17941: Already exists
5e161e9d6929: Pull complete
1d196bef415b: Pull complete
d5b12a7178d8: Pull complete
22b1f5727454: Pull complete
9882476be1ba: Pull complete
45a0a826653b: Pull complete
85edc2f3b545: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:f37f59c3bf7004e0315f32f5fca113c4388c42c69a7907fc32fb9ec440469363
Status: Downloaded newer image for php:7.0.10-alpine
```

2) tag the new image

```
~ # docker tag php:7.0.10-alpine localhost:5001/php:7.0.10-alpine
```

3)pushing the new image

```
~ # docker push localhost:5001/php:7.0.10-alpine
The push refers to a repository [localhost:5001/php]
c68fac7a8020: Pushed
0efd66c1278b: Pushed
2e576595708d: Pushed
651400f10523: Pushed
6c89d435ac6b: Pushed
01995d175b3e: Pushed
d14c7e8d2201: Pushed
4fe15f8d0ae6: Layer already exists
7.0.10-alpine: digest: sha256:19f2932709718d7f9c416b7241f04b23acc31e2b25628ef0008fb38d14a5b898 size: 1993
```

4) it took some space

```
~ # docker exec -it registry2 du -h -d 1  /var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/
24.0M   /var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/blobs
1.3M    /var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/repositories
25.3M   /var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/
```

5) garbage collector shows that we have something inside of php repository

```
~ # docker exec -it registry2 bin/registry garbage-collect /etc/docker/registry/config.yml
myfirstimage
myfirstimage1
myfirstimage2
myfirstimage3
myimage4
nginx
nginx-lalalal
php
php: marking manifest sha256:19f2932709718d7f9c416b7241f04b23acc31e2b25628ef0008fb38d14a5b898
php: marking blob sha256:328bb9d69b1a83435dde22af2cec2bf4c9d676f3c4a7fd9bc07d7b7a6a2d35c6
php: marking blob sha256:e110a4a1794126ef308a49f2d65785af2f25538f06700721aad8283b81fdfa58
php: marking blob sha256:5e161e9d6929b9a7736e565c6bb73c386617d410c1acb38b1f444b51c2d623b4
php: marking blob sha256:1d196bef415b6de51bf0b60843ff47d9875d6cbbdd8d12a54c61d3849bdefae4
php: marking blob sha256:d5b12a7178d880fd91653abf89153c0eaf2372868943c2f4fc2346677b424a56
php: marking blob sha256:22b1f5727454d36a41bb8d1bdf1672410a2023ddfed78906c17586b0d64f2ae7
php: marking blob sha256:9882476be1ba4aae95ae42d705ad7a8eb4eb8801ecfb064c0aeec582e7a89eb8
php: marking blob sha256:45a0a826653b594346eb78d2d72a1f1e0a5812ec5db56ee18e04c17f49c050b9
php: marking blob sha256:85edc2f3b5457034f2d4fc2a93018fb18ca98f15d953e2888e16471fd5ddf09d

10 blobs marked, 0 blobs eligible for deletion
```

6) deletion of image

```
curl -X DELETE http://localhost:5001/v2/php/manifests/sha256:19f2932709718d7f9c416b7241f04b23acc31e2b25628ef0008fb38d14a5b898
```

7)GC deleted bunch of blobs which belong to deleted manifest

```
~ # docker exec -it registry2 bin/registry garbage-collect /etc/docker/registry/config.yml
myfirstimage
myfirstimage1
myfirstimage2
myfirstimage3
myimage4
nginx
nginx-lalalal
php

0 blobs marked, 9 blobs eligible for deletion
blob eligible for deletion: sha256:45a0a826653b594346eb78d2d72a1f1e0a5812ec5db56ee18e04c17f49c050b9
INFO[0000] Deleting blob: /docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/45/45a0a826653b594346eb78d2d72a1f1e0a5812ec5db56ee18e04c17f49c050b9  go.version=go1.7.3 instance.id=ce04373e-0298-4a7a-90d3-c215335e9fdb
blob eligible for deletion: sha256:85edc2f3b5457034f2d4fc2a93018fb18ca98f15d953e2888e16471fd5ddf09d
INFO[0000] Deleting blob: /docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/85/85edc2f3b5457034f2d4fc2a93018fb18ca98f15d953e2888e16471fd5ddf09d  go.version=go1.7.3 instance.id=ce04373e-0298-4a7a-90d3-c215335e9fdb
blob eligible for deletion: sha256:d5b12a7178d880fd91653abf89153c0eaf2372868943c2f4fc2346677b424a56
INFO[0000] Deleting blob: /docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/d5/d5b12a7178d880fd91653abf89153c0eaf2372868943c2f4fc2346677b424a56  go.version=go1.7.3 instance.id=ce04373e-0298-4a7a-90d3-c215335e9fdb
blob eligible for deletion: sha256:19f2932709718d7f9c416b7241f04b23acc31e2b25628ef0008fb38d14a5b898
INFO[0000] Deleting blob: /docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/19/19f2932709718d7f9c416b7241f04b23acc31e2b25628ef0008fb38d14a5b898  go.version=go1.7.3 instance.id=ce04373e-0298-4a7a-90d3-c215335e9fdb
blob eligible for deletion: sha256:1d196bef415b6de51bf0b60843ff47d9875d6cbbdd8d12a54c61d3849bdefae4
INFO[0000] Deleting blob: /docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/1d/1d196bef415b6de51bf0b60843ff47d9875d6cbbdd8d12a54c61d3849bdefae4  go.version=go1.7.3 instance.id=ce04373e-0298-4a7a-90d3-c215335e9fdb
blob eligible for deletion: sha256:328bb9d69b1a83435dde22af2cec2bf4c9d676f3c4a7fd9bc07d7b7a6a2d35c6
INFO[0000] Deleting blob: /docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/32/328bb9d69b1a83435dde22af2cec2bf4c9d676f3c4a7fd9bc07d7b7a6a2d35c6  go.version=go1.7.3 instance.id=ce04373e-0298-4a7a-90d3-c215335e9fdb
blob eligible for deletion: sha256:22b1f5727454d36a41bb8d1bdf1672410a2023ddfed78906c17586b0d64f2ae7
INFO[0000] Deleting blob: /docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/22/22b1f5727454d36a41bb8d1bdf1672410a2023ddfed78906c17586b0d64f2ae7  go.version=go1.7.3 instance.id=ce04373e-0298-4a7a-90d3-c215335e9fdb
blob eligible for deletion: sha256:5e161e9d6929b9a7736e565c6bb73c386617d410c1acb38b1f444b51c2d623b4
INFO[0000] Deleting blob: /docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/5e/5e161e9d6929b9a7736e565c6bb73c386617d410c1acb38b1f444b51c2d623b4  go.version=go1.7.3 instance.id=ce04373e-0298-4a7a-90d3-c215335e9fdb
blob eligible for deletion: sha256:9882476be1ba4aae95ae42d705ad7a8eb4eb8801ecfb064c0aeec582e7a89eb8
INFO[0000] Deleting blob: /docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/98/9882476be1ba4aae95ae42d705ad7a8eb4eb8801ecfb064c0aeec582e7a89eb8  go.version=go1.7.3 instance.id=ce04373e-0298-4a7a-90d3-c215335e9fdb
```

8) space reduced

```
~ # docker exec -it registry2 du -h -d 1  /var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/
348.0K  /var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/blobs
1.3M    /var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/repositories
1.6M    /var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/
```

9) pushing the same image

```
 ~ # docker push localhost:5001/php:7.0.10-alpine
The push refers to a repository [localhost:5001/php]
c68fac7a8020: Layer already exists
0efd66c1278b: Layer already exists
2e576595708d: Layer already exists
651400f10523: Layer already exists
6c89d435ac6b: Layer already exists
01995d175b3e: Layer already exists
d14c7e8d2201: Layer already exists
4fe15f8d0ae6: Layer already exists
7.0.10-alpine: digest: sha256:19f2932709718d7f9c416b7241f04b23acc31e2b25628ef0008fb38d14a5b898 size: 1993
```

10) space was not changed

```
~ # docker exec -it registry2 du -h -d 1  /var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/
348.0K  /var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/blobs
1.3M    /var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/repositories
1.6M    /var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/
```

11) GC showed that we have nothing inside of repository

```
~ # docker exec -it registry2 bin/registry garbage-collect /etc/docker/registry/config.yml
myfirstimage
myfirstimage1
myfirstimage2
myfirstimage3
myimage4
nginx
nginx-lalalal
php

0 blobs marked, 0 blobs eligible for deletion
```

QUESTION:
How can I upload/push the same image into private Docker Registry?
Thanks

Comment: Can you try to restart your registry and push again?

Comment: found the opened  issue https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1803

Comment: @lorenzvth7 yes, I found that  it helps